# Is this function a probability density function?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{6}{10^5}  x^2 y & \text{$0<x<10$,  $0<y<10$} \\[1ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

1. is this a PDF function since double integral with limits sums to 1?
2. If 1 is True, can we say $x$ and $y$ (within support) are then random variables?

I would appreciate you reply.

P.s. I almost 40, I don't go to school anymore and I am not doing school homework. It's based on my interest.:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a pdf, since, as you already stated, the integral over the domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 1 and it is non-negative.

Calling $x$ and $y$ random variables is not correct. The answer is a bit more subtle, namely, you might define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that have joint density $f.$ A random variable is a function from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}.$ $x$ and $y$ here are just variables, not random variables. They are the arguments of the density function $f.$

Comment: I understand, thank you.